# What's the range of the TARDIS universal translator?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

The TARDIS has a universal translator, which accounts for his companions being able to speak to and understand those using foreign or truly alien languages.

This effect was played up in the episode *A Good Man Goes to War*, especially how it can't translate Gallifreyan.

Have we seen a point where the companions or others are too distant from the TARDIS to be under that effect?

Comment: It's as effective as the plot requires it to be.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's as may be, but one solid example will satisfy me.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of any episode where people left the range of the TARDIS and translation stopped working, only episodes where the TARDIS materialized or dematerialized while an alien language was present, or episodes where the TARDIS simply couldn't translate something to begin with. Maybe that means the range is so large it's never an issue in practice?

Comment: If I'm allowed to guess, I would say it has no range limit as in "_n_ and _m_ kilometers", since the T.A.R.D.I.S. can effectively communicate with every point of the time-space (except when the plot requires it not to...). I would say, it is limited by very complicated authorization rules instead. Anyone can be permitted to use it, but this permission is limited to certain people in certain time periods on their timeline.

Answer (score 4):

During the events of [The Christmas Invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Christmas_Invasion) when the Doctor was incapacitated Rose and company encountered the Sycorax, and had to rely on mechanical translation until the Doctor recovered.

For example, [Did you miss me?](https://youtu.be/liGD3vcnpHI)

Another (counter example), is the Genesis of the Daleks. The Doctor, Sarah and Harry were separated in time (and space) from the TARDIS; no problems communicating with Thals and Kaleds (both of whom, at that time, were unaware of the possibility of alien life - or, oddly, heavier than air flight).

Comment: How is that a range thing if the TARDIS is directly behind them?

Comment: @CreationEdge The [effect](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Translation_circuit) seems to depend on **both** the Doctor **and** the TARDIS. Another example was the Tritovores in Planet of the Dead. The Planet Skaro in the Genesis of the Daleks. No TARDIS at all, but humans and Kaleds and Thals (oh my).

Comment: In "Genesis", he was sent there by the Time Lords, so maybe they gave him some pocket translator or something.

Comment: @MrLister The Time Lords gave our fearless travelers a "time ring". And the Kaleds took it away from them.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sure, but it remained there in the facility; close by, and in the same time.

Comment: @MrLister Well, the TARDIS explodes at the beginning of [The Mind Robber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mind_Robber); but that's a silly episode. The telepathic circuit *works* through a "magic" fireplace (in The Girl in the Fireplace; a far more serious episode) for Mickey and Rose (and the Doctor can tell).

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, the translation circuit has a range

According to [the wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Translation_circuit):

> On yet another occasion, the Seventh Doctor told Elizabeth Klein that
> the telepathic field was limited to a certain radius around the
> TARDIS, with the Doctor losing the ability to communicate with the
> native Vrill in its absence, although this can be attributed to the
> fact that the Vrill communicated via smell and hence the Doctor would
> be unable to even attempt to speak it on his own.

This occurred in the audio adventure *Survival of the Fittest*. Transcribed from the episode:

> DOCTOR: The TARDIS has a special translation ability, remember. It makes all languages intelligible **within a certain radius around it**.

And if the TARDIS leaves that range:

> DOCTOR: The moment the TARDIS leaves this continuum, the gift will be revoked.
>
> KLEIN: The what?
>
> DOCTOR: The translation! There will be no more translation. Vrill and humans will be unable to communicate. Stefan or some fool like him will just repeat the cycle all over; the treaty will lost!

Note that in this case the TARDIS would be distant in time, as well as space, and possibly in a parallel timeline to boot.

Comment: Needless to say, I assume there has been some instance where this was entirely contradicted. This is *Doctor Who*, after all.

Comment: Unless the Doctor speaks Tritovore, the events of the Planet of the Dead would seem to be one such.

Comment: A Wikia reference? Dear dear, Jonah. Transcript quotes or no upvotes. :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - There's no transcript, so I have to listen to it myself. Patience, my friend.

Comment: I've never seen the original DW episodes (shame on me, I know), so this is definitely not something I would have had stored in memory. Eager for you to transcribe it yourself.

Comment: @Jonah Oh, I missed that it's an audio adventure. Perhaps you should state that in your header, since (to the extent that DW has canon at all) non-TV stories are normally considered a lower canon level than the main show.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Quotes added.